# Cron job template block not being translated, but testObserver is

Tags: product, cron, stock, locale, alert

I am configuring a product out of stock notification / alert, and I'm having an issue with localization / translation (pt_BR) in Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

The `email/productalert/stock.phtml` block isn't being translated when called by cron job. Nevertheless, when I call `/productalert/add/testObserver` it gets translated!

I am certain that when called by cron:

1. Module name is `Mage_ProductAlert`;
2. `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());` equals `pt_BR`;
3. `$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();` equals the same, `pt_BR`;

Any hints ? This is happening in core code, without any out of stock extensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, this is a bug indeed, but I came up with a fix!

The problem is that `Mage_Core_Model_Translate` translator isn't initialized by `cron.php`, since this script doesn't `load()` translate application area...

The fix is to initialize the translator after emulation, on `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email::send`:

```
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

//Dealing with uninitialized translator!
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);
```

I filled a bug with Magento so probably soon this patch will not be needed.

Comment: Patched in lasted version of Magento 1.9.x.

Comment: I found a similair issue with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::sendEmail()`. Thanks for the hint. It fix my issue!

Answer (score 2):

I think cronjobs run in admin store.

You could try a store emulation:

```
$emulation = Mage::getModel('core/app_emulation');
$oldEnvironment = $emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(
        $storeId,
        Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
        true
    );

//do the stuff

$emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($oldEnvironment);
```

Comment: You may be right! `Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');` is set on `cron.php`. There must be a reason for that...

Comment: I changed `cron.php`, added your snippet, and also added a `Mage::log` to `Mage_Core_Model_app::dispatchEvent`, `$area` is being assigned `global`, or `crontab`, but not `frontend`. The translation still doesn't work.

Comment: Magento uses this for sending order mails from the admin area. It just changes the design and the translations, not the current area. Have a look in `\Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` for this example. Did you instantiate the block after setting the environment emulation?

Comment: I just noticed that the `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email::send` around line 255 already was doing what you've suggested.