# Magento 1.9 alert emails not being translated

Tags: language, alert

I have configured price alerts for a client (which originally registered into my shop with spanish language).

The user receives the email, but it is in english.

For instance, the text: *"You are receiving this notification because you subscribed to receive alerts when the prices for the following products changed:"* (in ./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/price.phtml) is not being translated to spanish.

I have checked and the translation is present in ./app/locale/es_ES/Mage_ProductAlert.csv:
*"You are receiving this notification because you subscribed to receive alerts when the prices for the following products changed:","Usted está recibiendo esta notificación porque está suscrito para recibir alertas cuando los precios de los siguientes productos cambien:"*

I am using a custom theme.

I have also tried to add that translation to my theme: app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/locale/es_ES/translate.csv

I have flushed translations cache and deleted Magento cache. Still not being translated.

Is this a bug? How can I fix it? How can i debug it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: BUG SOLVED**
Ok, I found the fix thanks to
[Cron job template block not being translated, but testObserver is](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/cron-job-template-block-not-being-translated-but-testobserver-is)

What I did:
1) Edit app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Email.php

Replace this (line 255):

       `$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
       $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);`

With this:

        `$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
        //Dealing with uninitialized translator!
        Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);`

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer here and accept it later so that this question gets resolved? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Anna. Please excuse me, I was not aware of the right way to proceed ;)

Answer (score 2):

**The FIX to the bug:**

Edit `app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Email.php`

Replace this (line 255):

       `$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
       $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);`

With this:

        `$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
        //Dealing with uninitialized translator!
        Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);`

Now it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure are you save your .csv file in utf-8?Change email static content to spanish.From app/locale/es_ES/template/email/your-template.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Prashant. 

I had already translated the static contents of app/locale/es_ES/template/email/product_price_alert.html.

I have also made sure that the csv file is saved in utf8.

Still receiving the mail in english, though.

Any more ideas? How can I debug this?

Comment: also check system->configuration->general->locale is spanish selected ?

Comment: Yes, it is: Configuración regional = español (España).
Every other text in my website is correctly translated.

Comment: I just found the issue and edited my question.

Thanks anyways, Prashant.