# Cron Translate Email Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, cron, email-translation

Magento 2 still sending cron emails in English.

I know in Magento 1.9 is a recognized bug, but I tried with [the fixed known](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/cron-job-template-block-not-being-translated-but-testobserver-is) and it doesn't works.

I need to translate the product alert emails.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just solved it thanks to @nobodypb https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3805#issuecomment-225160290

Just add the `\Magento\Framework\App\AreaList` dependency.
And add this:

```
$areaObject = $this->_areaList->getArea(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
$areaObject->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

It works fine with my module! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found better solution here to translate all sales async emails using a plugin:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7426

It works perfect as expected.